# upgrade from Scala 2.11.8 to 2.12.10 build fails at sbt due to conflicting cross-version suffixes

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to upgrade my Scala version from 2.11.8 to 2.12.10. I made following changes in my sbt file.

```scala
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.7"  % "provided",

"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.7"   % "provided",

"com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "3.1.2_1.1.0" % "test"
```

when I am build the sbt file, I am getting following error

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/project/"), "root"):
[error]    io.reactivex:rxscala _2.12, _2.11
```

Tried following possible ways. but no luck.

1. `("io.reactivex" % "rxscala_2.12" % "0.27.0").force().exclude("io.reactivex","rxscala_2.11")`

2.Removed Scala verion=2.11.8 from File->project structure->global libraries.

Any Help will be very useful.

Comment: You might want to try `sbt dependencyTree` to see where the unwanted dependency comes from (if not set by yourself).

Comment: Also share your whole SBT file will be easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you could post your entire `build.sbt` file so it could be reproduced, but as a starting point, the dependency `spark-testing-base` is pointing to the wrong Spark version. From the [documentation](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base):

> So you include com.holdenkarau.spark-testing-base [spark_version]_1.0.0 and extend

Based on the information you have provided you should be using:

```
"com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "2.4.7_1.1.0" % "test"
```